# How to pass the CloudKit records data from "TableView-Controller B" to "View-Controller C"?

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit, pass-data, ckrecord

I've got records data from my `CloudKit` and show on `TableViewController-B` successfully, but how can i pass the `CloudKit's records(strings, images)` to next `ViewController-C`?? 
`ps. not tableViewcontroller-C`

my first `TableViewController-B`

```
import UIKit  
import CloudKit  

class BTableViewControoler: UITableViewController {
       var myclouds:[CKRecord] = []
       var imageCache = NSCache<CKRecordID, NSURL>()
       var recordType: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            recordsFromCloud()
        }

func recordsFromCloud() {

    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.default()
     let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase  
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

        queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "address", "GpNumber"]
        queryOperation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
        queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) -> Void in
            self.myclouds.append(record)
        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error { print("Failed data - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                 return }
        print("Successfully data")  
        }
        publicDatabase.add(queryOperation)     
    }//fetchRecords End

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return myclouds.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell


        let newInFo = myclouds[indexPath.row]

        cell.mainLabel.text = newInFo.object(forKey: "name") as? String
        cell.mainNumber.text = newInFo.object(forKey: "GpNumber") as? String
        cell.mainLocation.text = newInFo.object(forKey: "address") as? String
        cell.mainImage.image = UIImage(named: "photoalbum")

        //get image
        if let imageFileURL = imageCache.object(forKey: myclouds.recordID) {

            if let imageData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: imageFileURL as URL){
                cell.mainImage?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }else{

                let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
                let fetchRecordsImageOperation =   CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [newInFo.recordID])
                fetchRecordsImageOperation.desiredKeys = ["image"]
                fetchRecordsImageOperation.queuePriority = .veryHigh

                fetchRecordsImageOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {
                    (record, recordID, error) -> Void in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed image:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }

                    if let newinfoRecord = record {
                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
                    if let image = newinfoRecord.object(forKey: "image") {
                                let imageAsset = image as! CKAsset


                    if let imageData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: imageAsset.fileURL) {
                                    cell.mainImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                }

             self.imageCache.setObject(imageAsset.fileURL as NSURL, forKey: newInFo.recordID)

                            }
                         }
                    }//record end
                  }

             publicDatabase.add(fetchRecordsImageOperation)
          }//else end

          return cell
          }//cell end


//Segue To Next View 
       override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                   let toDetailVC = segue.destination as! showDetailVC
                        toDetailVC.DisData = newinfo[indexPath.row]       
                }
```

My ViewController-C

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class showDetailVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailpic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mynumberLabel: UILabel!

    var DisData: CKRecord?
    var getType: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detailpic.image = UIImage(named: "photoalbum")
        infoLabel.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "address") as? String
        nameLabel.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "name") as? String
        mynumberLable.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "GpNumber") as? String   
    }


}
```

I useing the `var DisData` to get the `CKRecord` from `tableViewController-B`
but it is not working by the method `DisData?.object(forKey: "name") as? String`
and the image also can't figure out how to show it.
Should I use the `UITableViewController-B's` `func recordsFromCloud` in `ViewController-C` again??? or any other smart way to get the `Cloudkit's records`, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a variable named selectedRecord

```
var selectedRecord: CKRecord!
```

add the delegate method didSelectRowatindexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedRecord = myclouds[indexPath.row]
performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailSegue", sender: nil)

}
```

Change the prepareforsegue to this

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {
                       let toDetailVC = segue.destination as! showDetailVC
                            toDetailVC.DisData = selectedRecord       
                    }
```

Change the type of DisData from `CKRecord?` to `CKRecord!` in `showDetailVC`

```
var DisData: CKRecord!
```

if you want to get your keys, declare the `queryOperation` **outside** the `recordsFromCloud()`

Then, make a variable forKeys in `showDetailVC`

```
var forKeys: [String]!
```

and add the following line to `prepareforsegue`

```
toDetailVC.forKeys = queryOperation.desiredKeys
```

Comment: It is still not working, there is no bug but don't show anythings, still working on it. thank you for the idea

Comment: It is working now. I need to make the `queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "address", "GpNumber"]` match the  `showDetailVC` Strings that's it,  but the image can't show up on `showDetailVC` I guess need to change the code `detailpic.image = UIImage(named: "photoalbum")` but don' know how to do it, can you fix the code? Appreciate the help so much.

Comment: Can you explain it again, what do you mean by 
queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "address", "GpNumber"] match the showDetailVC

Comment: yes!! In my project, My `showDetailVC`'s  'infoLabel.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "Gpaddress") as? String`
 `nameLabel.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "GpName") as? String`
`mynumberLable.text = DisData?.object(forKey: "Gpnumber") as? String` the forKeyes are different with what i post before, because I want to make my question code more easier to read by the helper.

Comment: so you want to pass the keys queryOperation.desireyKeys to showDetailVC?

Comment: yes and you resolve it. now i understand how to pass the differents `desireyKeys` from my CloudKit database. I always need to make sure the `showDetailVC`'s forKeys matched and already set up on `BTableViewController`'s  queryOperation.desireyKeys. Thank you so much to help me figure it out the problem.<br/>But still searching the way to show images on `showDetailVC` do you have any idea...really appreciate it~

Comment: your welcome, is the image showing up in the tableviewcell ??

Comment: appreciate the answer, and finally i figure out how to show the image on my `showDetailVC` : use the code in viewDidLoad  `if let imageFileURL = getImage.object(forKey: DisData.recordID) { if let imageData = try?Data.init(contentsOf: imageFileURL as URL) { detailpic?.image = UIImage(data. imageData) } }` , and declare a `var getImage = NSCache<CKRecordID, NSURL>()`  to receive the data from `imageCache` , that's it. thanks again~